# When you press space div moves up

Tags: javascript, html, space, cycle, onkeypress

I'm trying to do a tricky thing in Javascript, but it's not going well. Basically it's like: I have 2 balls(divs), one of them is on top: 100px and the other ball is on top 500px ( not actual values, just random ones ), and what I want to achieve is, when I press Space, the ball that is on top 500px, goes up to the top: 100px, and the other one does the opposite ( goes from top: 100px, to top: 500px, but with a cycle condition, like having speed, like a "for" that gives + 2px (or more) to the div until she reaches top: 500px, and vice versa.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to make here, a hand would be really appreciated.

Comment: Easier to solve your problem if you add some of your code related to your question

Comment: Its kinda easy to achieve with CSS 3 - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: I can't help you per se, but I recommend you write your code in a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). This makes it easier for other users to see where your code goes wrong, and can show the answer in real code as well

Comment: @brroshan the problem is, I don't have any code working for this, otherwise I would show you what my issue is. And it has to be in JS, sorry Ziv :D

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3nunwpdp/

Answer (score 0):

First you want to look up for events.

Events are "**things**" that happen to HTML elements. When JavaScript is used in HTML pages, JavaScript can "**react**" on these events. Found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp).

Next thing you want to learn about is how to **manipulate** with **DOM objects**. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp).

When you will know more about those two things, you will be ready to solve this problem, that you are asking this community to do it instead of you.